# what is the differnce between (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) and (/^[a-zA-Z]$/)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to java script so i had a doubt in regular expressions.what is the difference between the above mentioned regular expressions and what difference it will make to the final output?

Comment: Get a good resource such as [MDN Reg Exp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Though it is good you use regular expressions, that is nothing to do with javascript. There are plenty of resources over the net explaining the rules (even wikipedia page is quite good at it) Beside the doc, I find http://rubular.com quite handy to check your findings over real example (especially when starting to play with captures >< )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` indicates that the preceding item must occur one or more times.  Therefore, your second regex matches a string of length one and your first one matches a multi-character string.

Answer (score 1):

`[a-zA-Z]` matches a single character, if it is in the character range a-zA-Z. `+` means "one or more", so `[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more of those characters. `*` means 0 or more. `?` means 0 or 1. `{n}` matches exactly n times, `{n,}` n or more times, and `{n,m}` matches whatever comes before it between n or m times (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

This first matches any string consisting of only letters.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("Hello"); // true
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("f");     // true
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("9");     // false
```

The latter matches strings with only one character, which is a letter.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test("Hello");  // false
/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test("f");      // true
/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test("9");      // false
```